# Samba not working under ubuntu 21.10 impish

Tags: samba, smb, 21.10

my samba has stopped working on Ubuntu 21.10 impish not sure when it started but I get this on start:

```
$ sudo service smbd restart
[sudo] password for username: 
Job for smbd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status smbd.service" and "journalctl -xeu smbd.service" for details.
```

when I run the commands it  says to I get:

```
$ systemctl status smbd.service
× smbd.service - Samba SMB Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/smbd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-11-10 04:07:54 AEDT; 2min 6s ago
       Docs: man:smbd(8)
             man:samba(7)
             man:smb.conf(5)
    Process: 160601 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/samba/update-apparmor-samba-profile (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 160610 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group $SMBDOPTIONS (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)
   Main PID: 160610 (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)
     Status: "Starting process..."
        CPU: 44ms

Nov 10 04:07:54 pern smbd[160610]:   Ignoring unknown parameter "winbind trusted domains only"
Nov 10 04:07:54 pern smbd[160610]: [2021/11/10 04:07:54.175944,  0] ../../source3/auth/auth_util.c:1313(get_guest_info3)
Nov 10 04:07:54 pern smbd[160610]:   SamInfo3_for_guest: Unable to locate guest account []!
Nov 10 04:07:54 pern smbd[160610]: [2021/11/10 04:07:54.175995,  0] ../../source3/auth/auth_util.c:1385(make_new_session_info_guest)
Nov 10 04:07:54 pern smbd[160610]:   get_guest_info3 failed with NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER
Nov 10 04:07:54 pern smbd[160610]: [2021/11/10 04:07:54.176018,  0] ../../source3/smbd/server.c:2052(main)
Nov 10 04:07:54 pern smbd[160610]:   ERROR: failed to setup guest info.
Nov 10 04:07:54 pern systemd[1]: smbd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION
Nov 10 04:07:54 pern systemd[1]: smbd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 10 04:07:54 pern systemd[1]: Failed to start Samba SMB Daemon.
```

and

```
Subject: A start job for unit smbd.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit smbd.service has finished with a failure.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 14803 and the job result is failed.
Nov 10 04:07:54 pern systemd[1]: Starting Samba SMB Daemon...
░░ Subject: A start job for unit smbd.service has begun execution
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit smbd.service has begun execution.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 20143.
Nov 10 04:07:54 pern smbd[160610]: [2021/11/10 04:07:54.170769,  0] ../../lib/param/loadparm.c:815(lpcfg_map_parameter)
Nov 10 04:07:54 pern smbd[160610]:   Unknown parameter encountered: "password level"
Nov 10 04:07:54 pern smbd[160610]: [2021/11/10 04:07:54.170806,  0] ../../lib/param/loadparm.c:1855(lpcfg_do_global_parameter)
Nov 10 04:07:54 pern smbd[160610]:   Ignoring unknown parameter "password level"
Nov 10 04:07:54 pern smbd[160610]: [2021/11/10 04:07:54.170933,  0] ../../lib/param/loadparm.c:815(lpcfg_map_parameter)
Nov 10 04:07:54 pern smbd[160610]:   Unknown parameter encountered: "update encrypted"
Nov 10 04:07:54 pern smbd[160610]: [2021/11/10 04:07:54.170944,  0] ../../lib/param/loadparm.c:1855(lpcfg_do_global_parameter)
Nov 10 04:07:54 pern smbd[160610]:   Ignoring unknown parameter "update encrypted"
Nov 10 04:07:54 pern smbd[160610]: [2021/11/10 04:07:54.171032,  0] ../../lib/param/loadparm.c:815(lpcfg_map_parameter)
Nov 10 04:07:54 pern smbd[160610]:   Unknown parameter encountered: "winbind trusted domains only"
Nov 10 04:07:54 pern smbd[160610]: [2021/11/10 04:07:54.171040,  0] ../../lib/param/loadparm.c:1855(lpcfg_do_global_parameter)
Nov 10 04:07:54 pern smbd[160610]:   Ignoring unknown parameter "winbind trusted domains only"
Nov 10 04:07:54 pern smbd[160610]: [2021/11/10 04:07:54.175944,  0] ../../source3/auth/auth_util.c:1313(get_guest_info3)
Nov 10 04:07:54 pern smbd[160610]:   SamInfo3_for_guest: Unable to locate guest account []!
Nov 10 04:07:54 pern smbd[160610]: [2021/11/10 04:07:54.175995,  0] ../../source3/auth/auth_util.c:1385(make_new_session_info_guest)
Nov 10 04:07:54 pern smbd[160610]:   get_guest_info3 failed with NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER
Nov 10 04:07:54 pern smbd[160610]: [2021/11/10 04:07:54.176018,  0] ../../source3/smbd/server.c:2052(main)
Nov 10 04:07:54 pern smbd[160610]:   ERROR: failed to setup guest info.
Nov 10 04:07:54 pern systemd[1]: smbd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit smbd.service has exited.
░░ 
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 255.
Nov 10 04:07:54 pern systemd[1]: smbd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ The unit smbd.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 10 04:07:54 pern systemd[1]: Failed to start Samba SMB Daemon.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit smbd.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit smbd.service has finished with a failure.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 20143 and the job result is failed.
```

what is wrong?? it complains about lack of guest account but I do no want or use a guest account???

Answer (score 0):

Solved I created a user that cannot login and made that the the guest user, now I realise I could have made it user nobody seem to have the same properties then smbd started fine

Answer (score 0):

Samba also not working for me in Impish, slightly different error message.  Apparently related to unmasked `samba-ad-dc.service`.  This service has always been masked in the past, as I am fairly certain it conflicts with the client or file server-only version of Samba (the one almost everybody uses).

Error message:

```
$ sudo apt install -y samba
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  python3-samba samba-common samba-common-bin samba-dsdb-modules samba-libs
  samba-vfs-modules
Suggested packages:
  bind9 bind9utils ctdb ldb-tools ntp | chrony smbldap-tools ufw winbind
  heimdal-clients
Loaded services file OK.
Weak crypto is allowed
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

Done
Setting up samba (2:4.13.14+dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.10.4) ...
Samba is not being run as an AD Domain Controller: Masking samba-ad-dc.service
Please ignore the following error about deb-systemd-helper not finding those services.
(samba-ad-dc.service masked)
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/nmbd.service → /lib/systemd/system/nmbd.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/samba-ad-dc.service → /lib/systemd/system/samba-ad-dc.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/smbd.service → /lib/systemd/system/smbd.service.
Job for samba-ad-dc.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status samba-ad-dc.service" and "journalctl -xeu samba-ad-dc.service" for details.
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.4-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.34-0ubuntu3) ...
```

`apt` said `See "systemctl status samba-ad-dc.service" and "journalctl -xeu samba-ad-dc.service" for details.`, so...

```
$ sudo journalctl -xeu samba-ad-dc.service
░░
░░ The job identifier is 4924.
Dec 14 01:48:10 uminefi01 systemd[1]: samba-ad-dc.service: Main process exited,>
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit samba-ad-dc.service has exited.
░░
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Dec 14 01:48:10 uminefi01 systemd[1]: samba-ad-dc.service: Failed with result '>
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ The unit samba-ad-dc.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exi>
Dec 14 01:48:10 uminefi01 systemd[1]: Failed to start Samba AD Daemon.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit samba-ad-dc.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit samba-ad-dc.service has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 4924 and the job result is failed.
 ESCOC
```

Took your recommendation to create a user `nobody` (I don't think was necessary for this particular solution, but seemed like a good idea):

```
$ sudo smbpasswd -a nobody
New SMB password:        [enter on blank line]
Retype new SMB password: [enter on blank line]
Added user nobody.
```

Masked the `samba-ad-dc.service` unit:

```
systemctl mask samba-ad-dc.service
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/samba-ad-dc.service → /dev/null.
```

Ran package management autofixes:

```
$ sudo dpkg -a --configure && sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Enabled stand-alone Samba services (the 'normal' ones):

```
systemctl enable --now smbd nmbd
Synchronizing state of smbd.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable smbd
Synchronizing state of nmbd.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable nmbd
```

Ran `testparm` on generic package-maintainer's `smb.conf`, said all good ...

My `cockpit-zfs-manager` [from 45Drives](https://repo.45drives.com/setup.html) works again  ...